# How to fix.a keyboard that doesnt show emoji?

Tags: rooting, keyboard, 5.1-lollipop, emoticons

What i try : clear cache, data, restart Result still same

What i use : Android Slash Keyboard, Swiftkey, Chrooma, Go, still same.

How can i fix it?

[image: This what is look like]

Comment: Does this happen in every app that you try to use emoji?

Comment: Yes, its happen

Comment: Okay its fix for now i Use iOS 11.1 emoji from magisk manager. But its nice to hear any respond. It is my font problem or just what?